# embed image into mail body using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, lotus-notes

I am currently using the code below to send out emails from Access with an attachment. But I searched everywhere with no luck for a solution to get the attachment embedded into the email body itself. Anyone can help me out?

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

'Declare public object variables
Public mkfDoc As String
Public Subject, Attachment, Recipient, copyto, BodyText, UserName, SaveIt

Public Maildb As Object        'The mail database
Public MailDbName As String    'The current users notes mail database name
Public MailDoc As Object       'The mail document itself
Public AttachME As Object      'The attachment richtextfile object
Public Session As Object       'The notes session
Public EmbedObj As Object      'The embedded object (Attachment)


Public Function sendNotes(ByVal strTo As String, ByVal Attachment As String, ByVal strSubject As String, ByVal strBody As String)

'Set up the objects required for Automation into lotus notes
    Subject = strSubject
    'Attachment = "c:\foldername\filename.extension"
    Recipient = Split(strTo, ",")
'Set bodytext for mail offer - language depends on field in offprofrm
    BodyText = strBody
'Start a session to notes
        Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
'Open the mail database in notes
        Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
        If Maildb.ISOPEN = True Then
            'Already open for mail
        Else
            Maildb.OPENMAIL
        End If
'Set up the new mail document
        Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
        MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
        MailDoc.sendto = Recipient
        MailDoc.Subject = Subject
        MailDoc.Body = BodyText
        MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
        
        
'Set up the embedded object and attachment and attach it
        If Attachment <> "" Then
            Set AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Attachment")
            Set EmbedObj = AttachME.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", Attachment, "Attachment")
            MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM ("Attachment")
        End If
'Send the document + notify
        MailDoc.PostedDate = NOW() 'Gets the mail to appear in the sent items folder
        MailDoc.SEND 0, Recipient
'Clean Up
        Set Maildb = Nothing
        Set MailDoc = Nothing
        Set AttachME = Nothing
        Set Session = Nothing
        Set EmbedObj = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to create an email with included attachments in body field is to use the MIME format.

```
Set body = MailDoc.CreateMIMEEntity("Body") 
...
```

Have a look at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/bpmpblog.nsf/dx/creating-a-mime-email-with-attachment and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514633/2065611 how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only embed images in a rich text field using the Import method of the NotesUIDocument class, unless you want a much more complicated way.

The two ways I could see this being possible:
* Use Midas LSX from GeniiSoft (commercial product)
* Export the document as DXL, add the image (encoded as Base64) and then import the DXL back as a Notes document.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an outlook mail object, then, write the mail body (in html) with the appropriate <img src='myfile.jpg'> tag. Please note following points : 
    - embedded images must be save on your computer (as a jpg file or png file) ;
    **- Since outlook 2013, embedded images must be attached to the email as well.**

At the link below you will find all details and a working **code template**
http://vba-useful.blogspot.fr/2014/01/send-html-email-with-embedded-images.html

Comment: This question was about Lotus Notes, so I don't know how useful an Outlook answer will be....