# How to attach images to this email automation

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

The email automation in this code works, it was able to draft a template in outlook

```vb
Private Sub Command82_Click()
    
    Dim varName As Variant
    Dim varCC As Variant
    Dim varSubject As Variant
    Dim varBody As String
    
    
 
    varName = Forms!Contact!Email
    varCC = "XXXX"

    
    varSubject = " XXX"
    'Email subject
    
    varBody = " XXXXX"

    'Body of the email
    
    DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, varCC, , varSubject, varBody, True, False
    'Send email command. The True after "varBody" allows user to edit email before sending.
    'The False at the end will not send it as a Template File

End Sub
```

But I could not paste any image in the body of the email.

Is there any changes that i can make in this code to paste an image in the body of the email ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba

Comment: If you do use the code in the [Embed picture in outlook mail body excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44869790/embed-picture-in-outlook-mail-body-excel-vba) delete `On Error Resume Next`. If there is an error handle it any other way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed an image into an Outlook email using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617458/how-to-embed-an-image-into-an-outlook-email-using-vba)

Comment: Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634599/embed-image-into-mail-body-using-access-vba

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I don't want to attach any Image from a folder. I was looking to paste SS every time in the body of the email. My guess is that since Varbody is declared as String, it is not allowing to paste images. Is there anyway that i can make changes in the same code ?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77655591/edit) the question. Describe SS and where it comes from. Add a sample result showing SS.

Comment: Your title says "attach", your narrative says "paste" - so there was some confusion. Your code will include the report as an attachment but if you want to paste images into opened email object, then need to use Outlook automation as shown in referenced links to create an HTMLBody. And if you still want to include the report, will have to first save out to PDF file then attach with the Attachments property.